# Plot ellipse hypothesis plots with confidence intervals for multiple models

Tags: r, statistics

I have developed a function to graphically plot between two predictors of interest their confidence interval regions on an ellipse. It states whether the null hypotheses have been accepted for the one-sided and two-sided tests. Additionally, I have included points on the plots to identify the confidence interval and the origin.

It complements my previous function posted for review [All permutations of a linear model given all predictors](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/277126/all-permutations-of-a-linear-model-given-all-predictors). Therefore, I would essentially use that function to get all combinations of a linear model for predictors of interest, and then plug it into the graphical function to test against the Null-hypothesis.

Here's how it works:

```
#in this case I used the dataset: diabetes
perPlot(models=lmod, predictors=c('age','weight'), type='l')
```

Here's an example plot, bear in mind this plot has got lots of predictors:
[image]

Alternatively, I would largely appreciate how to handle the sub-headings. The sub-headings contains the formula to the linear model, I want to make these research-presentable so I am happy to any criticism/suggestions.

Depending on the size of your computer screen and the image, if small then the text is squashed whereas if the image is large the text is evenly spaced unless the sub-headings are too large.

Here's my script:

```
perPlot <- function(data, predictors=NULL, type=NULL){
  require(ellipse)
  
  models <- 
    data %>% 
    keep( ~ all(length(names(.$model)) > 2))
  
  if (length(predictors) < 2) {
    stop('You need two predictors only')
  } else if (length(predictors) > 2) {
    stop('You need two predictors only')
  } else{
    
  models <- 
    models %>%
    keep(~all(predictors %in% names(.$model))) 
  
  true_false_list<-
    models %>% sapply(., function(x)
      x$coefficients %>% 
        data.frame(.) %>% 
        unlist() %>% 
        setNames(., names(x$coefficients)) %>%
        .[predictors]  %>% 
        is.na(.) %>%
        {
        TRUE %in% .
      } %>% list() )
  
  true_false <- true_false_list %>% unlist()
  
  if (all(true_false) == TRUE) {
    stop('All your models has a predictor with NAs; Either pick another predictor or fix the NAs')
  } else if (TRUE %in% true_false) {
    models <-
      mapply(function(x, y) {
        if (FALSE %in% y)
          x}, models, true_false_list, SIMPLIFY = FALSE) %>% Filter(Negate(is.null), .)
  }
  
  ln <- length(models)
  
  par(mfrow = n2mfrow(ln, asp=2))

  row_predictor_data <-
    lapply(models, function(x)
    names(x$coefficients) %>%
      seq_along() %>% as.factor() %>%
      data.frame(id = ., name = as.factor(names(x$coefficients))))

  row_predictor_value <-lapply(row_predictor_data, function(x) match(predictors, x$name) %>% setNames(., predictors))

  confint_model <- models %>%
    lapply(., function(x)
      confint(x) %>%
        data.frame(.) %>%
        rownames_to_column(.) %>%
        `colnames<-`(c('predictor', 'X2.5%', 'Y97.5%')) %>%
        .[.$predictor %in% predictors, ])

  confint_model <- lapply(confint_model, function(x) x[match(predictors, x$predictor),])
  #
  confint_model <- confint_model %>%
    keep( ~all(predictors %in% .$predictor))

  confint_model_add <- confint_model %>% lapply(., function(x)
    x[,-1] %>%
      rowid_to_column(.) %>%
      pivot_longer(-c(1)) %>%
      data.frame(.) %>%
      mutate(name = glue("{name}{rowid}")) %>%
      .[,-1] %>%
      pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value) %>% data.frame(.))
  #
  confint_all_models <-
    mapply(function(x, y) {
      if (!'NA' %in% x)
        cbind(x, y)
    }, confint_model_add, row_predictor_value, SIMPLIFY = FALSE) %>% Filter(Negate(is.null), .)

  confint_all_models <-
    lapply(confint_all_models, function(x)
      rownames_to_column(x) %>% pivot_wider(names_from = rowname, values_from = y))
  #
  # #colum names for row_predictor_value
  # #`X2.5%1` `Y97.5%1` `X2.5%2` `Y97.5%2`

  #formula text
  formula_text <-
    lapply(models, function(x)
      formula(x) %>% deparse() %>% str_trim(.)%>% paste(., collapse="") %>% gsub(" ","",.) ) 

  confint_all_models <-
    mapply(function(x, y)
      cbind(x, y) %>% data.frame(),
      confint_all_models,
      formula_text,
      SIMPLIFY = FALSE)


  lower_conf <- lapply(confint_all_models, function(x) {
    if (x[[1]] < 0 &
        0 < x[[2]]) {
      "Accept"
    } else {
      "Reject"
    }
  })
  total_conf <- lapply(confint_all_models, function(x) {
    if (x[[1]] < 0 &
        0 < x[[2]] & x[[3]] < 0 &
        0 < x[[4]]) {
      "Accept"
    } else  {
      "Reject"
    }
  })

  upper_conf <- lapply(confint_all_models, function(x) {
    if (x[[3]] < 0 &
        0 < x[[4]]) {
      "Accept"
    } else {
      "Reject"
    }
  })

  confint_all_models <-
    mapply(
      function(x, y, z, q)
        cbind(x, y, z, q),
      confint_all_models,
      lower_conf,
      upper_conf,
      total_conf,
      SIMPLIFY = FALSE
    )

  #
   mapply(
     function(x, y)
       plot(ellipse(x, predictors), type = type) %>%
       with(
         points(coef(x)[y[[5]]], coef(x)[y[[6]]], pch = 19)) %>%
       with(
         points(y[[1]], y[[3]], pch = 22)
       ) %>%
       with(
         points(y[[2]], y[[4]], pch = 24)
       ) %>%
       with(
         points(0, 0, pch=19, col='red')
       ) %>%
       with(
         title(sub = y[[7]]))  %>%
       with(
         mtext(text = TeX(paste0('$H_0:$', glue('$\\beta_{1} = 0, {y[[8]]}$') )),cex=0.5,   adj=0)
       ) %>%with(
         mtext(text  = TeX(paste0('$H_0:$', glue('$\\beta_{2} = 0, {y[[9]]}$') )),cex=0.5,  adj=1)
       ) %>%with(
         mtext(text = TeX(paste0('$H_0:$', glue('$\\beta_{1} = \\beta_{2} = 0, {y[[10]]}$') )) , cex=0.5)
       ) %>%
       with(abline(v = confint(x)[y[[5]], ], lty = 2)) %>%
       with(abline(h = confint(x)[y[[6]], ], lty = 2)),
     models,
     confint_all_models
   )
   return('enjoy your plot(s)')
  # 
  }
  }
```