# Permutation of linear models with Python

Tags: python

Similar to my previous post in R [All permutations of a linear model given all predictors](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/277126/all-permutations-of-a-linear-model-given-all-predictors), I have attempted a Pythonic version. However, a few issues that I have with my version is that I cannot select for multiple predictors beside when using `all`.

For example, if I wanted:

```
perModel(savings, response='sr', predictors=['pop15', 'pop75'])
```

It throws an error so I still need to working on including lists. However, the following works:

```
perModel(savings, response='sr', predictors='all')
perModel(savings, response='sr', predictors='pop15')
```

Update:

1. I have fixed the issue with log transformations. I had to use `np.log` on the variable.
2. The issue with multiple predictors was fixed also.

Here is my code:

```
import re
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
import faraway.datasets.savings

savings = faraway.datasets.savings.load()

def reformulate(predictors, response):
    form = response + "~" + '+'.join(predictors)
    return(form)
    
def perModel(data, response, predictors):
    response = response
    if '(' in response:
        response_val = re.search('(?<=\\()[^\\^\\)]+', response).group(0)
        nm = data.columns.values
        nm = [x for x in nm if response_val != x]
        nm = np.array(nm)
        
    else:
        nm = data.columns.values
        nm = [x for x in nm if response != x]
        nm = np.array(nm)

    n = len(nm)
    #Alternatively, there are faster options by using circulant from scipy
    md_arrange =linalg.circulant(nm)
    #md_arrange = [nm[x:] + nm[:x] for x in range(1, len(nm)+1)]    
    df = pd.DataFrame(md_arrange)
    ls_comb = [df.loc[0:i] for i in range(0, len(df))]

    if 'all' in predictors:
        predictors_wanted = ls_comb
    else:
        test_val = ['(' in i for i in [predictors]]
        extract_text = []
        clean_text = ''

        for bl, pred in zip(test_val, [predictors]):
            if bl:
                clean_text=(pred)
                extract_text=(re.search('(?<=\\()[^\\^\\)]+', pred).group(0))
            else:
                extract_text=(pred)
        
        if clean_text != '': 
            repl_predictors = [i.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(extract_text, clean_text)) for i in ls_comb]
        else:
            repl_predictors = ls_comb

        predictors_wanted = [df.loc[:, df.columns[df.apply(lambda col: col.str.contains("|".join(extract_text))).any()]]
                                for df in repl_predictors]
    formula_predictors = pd.concat(pd.concat([x]) for x in [i.apply(
    lambda x: reformulate(x, response)
                    ).reset_index().drop(['index'], axis=1
                                        ) if len(i) < n else i[[1]].apply(
                        lambda x: reformulate(x, response)
                    ).reset_index().drop(['index'], axis=1
                    ) for i in predictors_wanted ]).rename(columns = {0:'formula'})

    models =  [smf.ols(i, data).fit().summary() for i in formula_predictors['formula']]
    #formula_predictors.to_csv("test.csv")
    return(models)
```